# Spring Data Rest and count queries

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I was experimenting few lines of code using Spring Data Rest. I cannot find anything for sending via REST a simple request to count all records for a specific entity.

Suppose I have the following entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

which shall be accessed with the following repository:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

Is there a way for knowing with REST how many `Person` entity are saved in my database, no condition specified?

Comment: PagingAndSortingRepository has a findAll() methods returning Iterable. Maybe this is what you are looking for? Or count() method?

Comment: Yes but how can I call it using REST, for example, with Postman?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data REST [serves](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources) only standard HTTP methods such as GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE etc.

But if you need to get total number of resources you can, for example, make the GET request and check its page block:

```
  "page" : {
    "size" : 5,
    "totalElements" : 50,
    "totalPages" : 10,
    "number" : 1 
  }
```

or create the [custom controller](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers).

**UPDATED**

For [GET method on collection resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_get) SDR returns pageable result with total number of resource elements. SDR fires two select queries: one for elements on the page and second - the **count** query for all elements.

Comment: Hmmm... so... totalElements field shows how many records are available for a query. I understood that it shows me how many records are in the current page that I have received. Am I right?

Comment: @Lorelorelore No, it's a number of _total elements_. But `size` - is a size of the page.

Comment: Ok, now it is clear. You helped me a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative would be to introduce a custom query method. These methods are exposed via the REST data repositories.

For example, using JPA:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {
    @Query("select count(p) from Person p")
    Long findCount();
}
```

Using MongoDB:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, Long> {
    @Query(value = "{}", count = true)
    Long findCount();
}
```

Then to call it from rest, it's just `/people/search/findCount`, which returns just the number in the body with no extra properties, e.g.:

```
200 success

date: Wed, 09 May 2018 17:59:13 GMT
transfer-encoding: chunked
content-type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8

154
```

No need to parse the GET response and unnecessarily fetch records.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like count() method of CrudRepository is your candidate. According to the javadoc:

```
/**
 * Returns the number of entities available.
 * 
 * @return the number of entities
 */
long count();
```

Comment: Yes but how can I call it using REST, for example, with Postman?

Comment: This method isn't exposed by Spring Data REST.